# fastJSON Deserialization List

Tags: c#, json, serialization, unity-game-engine, fastjson

So sort of a build on from a previous question of mine. I am trying to save a blueprint, which is just a heap of settings for a gameobject/Entity. I'm now storing the components (And their settings) as a List < IEntityComponent > (IEntityComponent is the interface for any component) wrapped in a class called ComponentTable. I only want to serialize the list, and all the private stuff is not serialized, and is just for faster look ups (At the price of memory). This serializes properly and even deserializes without any errors, but i noticed the componentTable isn't deserializing PROPERLY.

It creates an instance of ComponentTable, but never actually adds the values to it. So instead of a Component table containing CameraComponent, VelocityComponent and InputComponent, it just just an empty ComponentTable.

```
{
 "$types" : {
  "ECS.Framework.Collections.Blueprint, Assembly-CSharp, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" : "1",
  "ECS.Features.Core.CameraComponent, Assembly-CSharp, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" : "2",
  "ECS.Features.Core.VelocityComponent, Assembly-CSharp, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" : "3",
  "InputComponent, Assembly-CSharp, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" : "4"
 },
 "$type" : "1",
 "Components" : [
  {
     "$type" : "2",
     "Tag" : "MainCamera",
     "Test" : "0, 0, 0",
     "BackgroundColour" : "0, 0, 1, 1",
     "ViewportRect" : "10, 10 : 10, 10",
     "Orthographic" : false,
     "FieldOfView" : 60,
     "OrthoSize" : 5,
     "Depth" : 0,
     "OcclusionCulling" : true,
     "HDR" : false,
     "Enabled" : true
  },
  {
     "$type" : "3",
     "Enabled" : true,
     "CurrentVelocity" : "0, 0, 0"
  },
  {
     "$type" : "4",
     "TEST" : 0,
     "Enabled" : true
  }
 ],
 "Children" : [

 ],
 "Parent" : ""
}
```

This is how it saves, so it seems like it is saving correctly. I am only controlling the serialization/serialization of the Vectors, Rect and colors, as any unity value types cause errors.

I believe it is serializing properly, but for some reason it is not deserializing into the componentTable. Does anyone know if fastJSON has problems with this kind of inheritance (Making a class inherit from a List< customClass >?

Ideally i would have it inherit as a Dictionary< Type, IEntityComponent >, but fastJSON wont serialize the Type, just saves it as 'System.Mono' then causes an error when serializing.

Edit: Here are the blueprint and component Table classes

```
public sealed class Blueprint 
{
    public ComponentTable Components { get; private set; }

    public List<string> Children { get; set; }

    public string Parent { get; set; }

    public Blueprint()
    {
        Components = new ComponentTable();

        Children = new List<string>();
        Parent = "";
    }

    public Blueprint(Blueprint _blueprint)
    {
        Children = new List<string>(_blueprint.Children);

        Parent = _blueprint.Parent;
    }
}


public class ComponentTable : List<IEntityComponent>
{
    private Dictionary<Type, IEntityComponent> Components { get; set; }

    #region Constructors

    public ComponentTable()
    {
        Components = new Dictionary<Type, IEntityComponent>();
    }

    #endregion

    #region Base Function Overrides

    public void Add(Type _type)
    {
        if (Components.ContainsKey(_type))
            return;

        InternalAdd(_type, (IEntityComponent)Activator.CreateInstance(_type));
    }
    public new void Add(IEntityComponent _component)
    {
        InternalAdd(_component.GetType(), _component);
    }
    public void Add<T>() where T : IEntityComponent
    {
        Add(typeof(T));
    }
    private void InternalAdd(Type _type, IEntityComponent _component)
    {
        if (Components.ContainsKey(_type))
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Component already contained");

        Components.Add(_type, _component);
        base.Add(_component);
    }

    public bool Remove(Type _type)
    {
        if (Components.ContainsKey(_type))
            return InternalRemove(_type, Components[_type]);
        return false;
    }
    public new bool Remove(IEntityComponent _component)
    {
        return InternalRemove(_component.GetType(), _component);
    }
    public bool Remove<T>() where T : IEntityComponent
    {
        return Remove(typeof(T));
    }
    private bool InternalRemove(Type _type, IEntityComponent _component)
    {
        if (!Components.ContainsKey(_type))
            return false;

        Components.Remove(_type);
        return base.Remove(_component);
    }

    public IEntityComponent Get(Type _type)
    {
        if (Contains(_type))
            return Components[_type];
        return null;
    }
    public T Get<T>() where T : IEntityComponent
    {
        return (T)Get(typeof(T));
    }

    public bool TryGetValue(Type _type, out IEntityComponent _component)
    {
        return Components.TryGetValue(_type, out _component);
    }
    public bool TryGetValue<T>(out IEntityComponent _component) where T : IEntityComponent
    {
        return TryGetValue(typeof(T), out _component);
    }

    public bool Contains(Type _type)
    {
        return Components.ContainsKey(_type);
    }
    public new bool Contains(IEntityComponent _component)
    {
        return Contains(_component.GetType());
    }
    public bool Contains<T>() where T : IEntityComponent
    {
        return Contains(typeof(T));
    }

    #endregion

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tested this a bit on Microsoft .Net, and found the following issues:

1. [fastJSON](https://github.com/mgholam/fastJSON) will not deserialize the `Components` property unless it has a public setter:

   ```
   public sealed class Blueprint 
   {
       public ComponentTable Components { get; set; }
   ```

   There doesn't appear to be any sort of configuration option to work around this.  From [`Reflection.cs`](https://github.com/mgholam/fastJSON/blob/master/fastJSON/Reflection.cs) you can see the method to create the setter delegate returns `null` if the setter is not public:

   ```
   internal static GenericSetter CreateSetMethod(Type type, PropertyInfo propertyInfo)
   {
       MethodInfo setMethod = propertyInfo.GetSetMethod();
       if (setMethod == null)
           return null;
   ```
2. fastJSON does indeed appear to be unable to deserialize a subclass of `List<T>` -- or any other non-array collection class -- that *is not generic*.  Inside the [deserializer](https://github.com/mgholam/fastJSON/blob/master/fastJSON/JSON.cs) there is the following check:

   ```
   if (pi.IsGenericType && pi.IsValueType == false && v is List<object>)
       oset = CreateGenericList((List<object>)v, pi.pt, pi.bt, globaltypes);
   ```

   As you can see, it checks for the target type being generic, rather than the target type or one of its base types being generic.

   You could work around this by making your `ComponentTable` be generic:

   ```
   public class ComponentTable<TEntityComponent> : List<TEntityComponent> where TEntityComponent : IEntityComponent
   {
       private Dictionary<Type, TEntityComponent> Components { get; set; }

       #region Constructors

       public ComponentTable()
       {
           Components = new Dictionary<Type, TEntityComponent>();
       }

       #endregion

       #region Base Function Overrides

       public void Add(Type _type)
       {
           if (Components.ContainsKey(_type))
               return;

           InternalAdd(_type, (TEntityComponent)Activator.CreateInstance(_type));
       }
       public new void Add(TEntityComponent _component)
       {
           InternalAdd(_component.GetType(), _component);
       }
       public void Add<T>() where T : IEntityComponent
       {
           Add(typeof(T));
       }
       private void InternalAdd(Type _type, TEntityComponent _component)
       {
           if (Components.ContainsKey(_type))
               throw new InvalidOperationException("Component already contained");

           Components.Add(_type, _component);
           base.Add(_component);
       }

       public bool Remove(Type _type)
       {
           if (Components.ContainsKey(_type))
               return InternalRemove(_type, Components[_type]);
           return false;
       }
       public new bool Remove(TEntityComponent _component)
       {
           return InternalRemove(_component.GetType(), _component);
       }
       public bool Remove<T>() where T : IEntityComponent
       {
           return Remove(typeof(T));
       }
       private bool InternalRemove(Type _type, TEntityComponent _component)
       {
           if (!Components.ContainsKey(_type))
               return false;

           Components.Remove(_type);
           return base.Remove(_component);
       }

       public IEntityComponent Get(Type _type)
       {
           if (Contains(_type))
               return Components[_type];
           return null;
       }
       public T Get<T>() where T : IEntityComponent
       {
           return (T)Get(typeof(T));
       }

       public bool TryGetValue(Type _type, out TEntityComponent _component)
       {
           return Components.TryGetValue(_type, out _component);
       }
       public bool TryGetValue<T>(out TEntityComponent _component) where T : IEntityComponent
       {
           return TryGetValue(typeof(T), out _component);
       }

       public bool Contains(Type _type)
       {
           return Components.ContainsKey(_type);
       }
       public new bool Contains(TEntityComponent _component)
       {
           return Contains(_component.GetType());
       }
       public bool Contains<T>() where T : IEntityComponent
       {
           return Contains(typeof(T));
       }

       #endregion
   }
   ```

   Then change `Blueprint` to be:

   ```
   public sealed class Blueprint
   {
       public ComponentTable<IEntityComponent> Components { get; set; }
   ```

   And the list contents will be deserialized.  However...
3. Your `ComponentTable` is inheriting from `List<T>` and needs to override `Add()`.  But `Add()` is not virtual, and so you are using `public new Add()` instead.  The problem here is that if anybody casts your class to a `List<T>` and calls `Add()`, your method won't get called.  In particular, fastJSON will not call it during deserialization!  So your type dictionary is never initialized during deserialization, defeating the purpose.

   What it appears you are doing is re-inventing [`KeyedByTypeCollection<TItem>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404549%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).  Rather than do that, you can just use it.  Using this class, your `ComponentTable` becomes very simple:

   ```
   public class ComponentTable<TEntityComponent> : KeyedByTypeCollection<TEntityComponent> where TEntityComponent : IEntityComponent
   {
       public void Add(Type _type)
       {
           if (Contains(_type))
               return;
           Add((TEntityComponent)Activator.CreateInstance(_type));
       }

       public void Add<T>() where T : IEntityComponent, new()
       {
           Add(typeof(T));
       }
   }
   ```

   Now the collection can be serialized and deserialized with no data corruption on Microsoft .Net.  However...
4. I'm not sure that `KeyedByTypeCollection<TItem>` exists in unity.  If not, you may need to port it.  See the reference source [`KeyedByTypeCollection.cs`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.ServiceModel/System/ServiceModel/KeyedByTypeCollection.cs) and the base class source [`keyedcollection.cs`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/objectmodel/keyedcollection.cs).  One attempt to do it can be found here: [Alternative to KeyedByTypeCollection in Mono .Net](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/925783/alternative-to-keyedbytypecollection-in-mono-net.html).
5. As an alternative, you might consider using Json.NET.  Json.NET supports serializing polymorphic types via the [`TypeNameHandling` setting](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializeTypeNameHandling.htm).  But, is it available on unity?

   [Google suggests](https://encrypted.google.com/search?q=json.net+unity3d) that there are some ports for unity.  There are also a variety of questions here [tagged with both Json.NET and unity3d](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/json.net+unity3d), for instance [JSON .Net Unity Deserialize dictionary of anonymous objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28698658/json-net-unity-deserialize-dictionary-of-anonymous-objects).  So, you might investigate that option further.

Comment: Seriously top answer 10/10. You put so much more detail into that than i expected, thank you so much. I didn't realize the class KeyedByTypeCollection even existed, i will try changing that around and seeing how it works with fastJSON. I'm assuming you tried serializing it with fastJSON and it worked? Honestly i could use a different JSON, even fastJSON wasn't part of unity and i had to import it, it just happened to be the first one i found. Plus it seemed fast, and had plenty of features. But it keeps running into problems like these so i might change it over

Comment: @Lolop - I round-tripped `KeyedByTypeCollection<TItem>` successfully using fastJSON successfully on Microsoft .Net.  I don't have unity so I couldn't test there.

Comment: You're a God send. I did have to copy those classes into unity, and fix anything that didn't work with unity. The only problem was what they use to throw errors, i had to replace them (Hopefully not to my detriment) with just normal exceptions. This is because (I'm assuming) unity uses .Net 3.5, whereas the stuff they were using in the KeyedByType and it's baseclass was .Net 4.5+? (Also probably why it isn't in unity to begin with). Again thank you so much, i probably never would have figured it out. The private setting was stopping deserialization, but the generic thing was breaking it.